# Resource Booking in SharePoint

Tags: 2010, exchange-server, resources

I am trying to integrate Exchange Server with SharePoint 2010. I need to get all the Exchange resource Mailboxes in to a SharePoint list. I need to use this SharePoint list as a source for resource booking in SharePoint. Please let me know how can I achieve this.

Answer (score 2):

In SharePoint 2010, [group calendar feature](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-server-help/enable-reservation-of-resources-in-a-calendar-HA101810595.aspx#_Toc246759864) enables you to book resources like rooms, equipments etc without having to write a single line of code. You can even create [calendar overlays with](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2641729) your Exchange Server in a single SharePoint Calendar

Hoping against hope, if you want a very specific custom solution you can use [Exchange Server Managed API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dd633702%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx) or classic Exchange Web Services (EWS) to fetch or update the resources like Rooms etc. You can find the difference between the two approaches [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dd633678%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx).

Comment: Thanks Falak. Its very useful. But, I want to create a two-way connection between the Exchange Resource Mailboxes and with Group Calendar. How can I achieve that?